# Setting up a web dev project

Tags: html, css, laravel, tailwind-css

Please I want to know how I can be able to set up a good project structure with using html css/ tailwind and laravel for nice looking ui project

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to view tailwind documentation which is great.

Here you can find how to setup project for `laravel`

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel

I recommend try to use only `tailwind` if you want improve you CSS skills and knowledge but if you need some `tailwind UI` frameworks then here are some:

https://daisyui.com/

https://merakiui.com/components/

https://www.material-tailwind.com/

https://preline.co/index.html